# Matplotlib animation slows down every time I plot more data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting sensor data in real-time. Let's say I store my sensor_data in a dictionary. Every time I plot a new set of sensor_data, it slows down the plotting speed.

I know there is a way to speed this up. I tried several methods (i.e. blit, saving and loading background) but cannot get the syntax or method right. I am hoping there is some way to speed up my frames per second as this is slowing everything down. I think I have exhausted existing stack overflows on this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_init():

    plt.ion() # interactive mode on
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.show(block=False)

    # set title according to axis
    ax[0, 0].set(title='Sensor 1')
    ax[0, 1].set(title='Sensor 2')
    ax[1, 0].set(title='Sensor 3')
    ax[1, 1].set(title='Sensor 4')

    # turn on grid for each subplot
    for a in fig.axes:
        a.grid()

    return fig, ax

def plot_sensor_data(fig, ax, sensor_data):

    plot1, = ax[0, 0].plot(sensor_data["some_sensor"], 'C0')
    plot2, = ax[0, 0].plot(sensor_data["some_other_sensor"], 'C1')
    ax[0, 0].legend([plot1, plot2], ['some_sensor', 'some_other_sensor'])

    # ...

    axes[1, 1].plot(sensor_data["another_sensor"], 'C0')

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sensor_data = {}
    fig, ax = plot_init()

    while True:

        sensor_data = get_sensor_data() 
        plot_sensor_data(fig, ax, sensor_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution that works for me.

```
class SensorPlot():

    def __init__(self):

        plt.show()

        self.sample = 0

        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []

        self.xdata2 = []
        self.ydata2 = []

        self.xdata3 = []
        self.ydata3 = []

        fig, self.axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10))

        for a in fig.axes:
            a.grid()

        self.line1, = self.axes[0,0].plot(self.ydata)
        self.line2, = self.axes[0,0].plot(self.ydata2)
        self.axes[0, 0].legend([self.line1, self.line2], ['some_sensor', 'some_other_sensor'])

        self.line3, = self.axes[0, 1].plot(self.ydata3)
        self.axes[0, 1].legend([self.line3, self.line4], ['another_sensor'])

        # ...

    def plot_data(self, my_bud):

        self.xdata.append(self.sample)

        self.ydata.append(sensor_data["some_sensor"][-1])
        self.line1.set_xdata(self.xdata)
        self.line1.set_ydata(self.ydata)

        self.ydata2.append(sensor_data["some_other_sensor"][-1])
        self.line2.set_xdata(self.xdata)
        self.line2.set_ydata(self.ydata2)

        self.ydata3.append(sensor_data["another_sensor"][-1])
        self.line3.set_xdata(self.xdata)
        self.line3.set_ydata(self.ydata3)

        self.sample = self.sample + 1

        self.axes[0,0].relim()
        self.axes[0,0].autoscale_view(True, True, True)

        self.axes[1,0].relim()
        self.axes[1,0].autoscale_view(True, True, True)

        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(1e-17)
```

Comment: Can you also explain in words what you exactly did?